# delete file shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

This question is on one of my assignments. I know how to create the files but i'm stuck on how to delete `foo foo1 foo2` and `foo4` but not `foo3`. and also how to run

```
$ ksh <  to_delete.shl.
```

Write a shell script; named `to_delete.shl`; that will create file of these files with the `rm` command.  Edit the file and remove `foo3` from being deleted The intention is to use the following command to delete these file

```
$ ksh <  to_delete.shl.
```

Comment: ksh is not bash.

Comment: your file is *.shl or .sh?

Comment: My file its called to_delete.shl

Comment: `rm foo foo1 foo2 foo4` does not remove foo3.  I'm afraid your question is unclear and/or incomplete.

Comment: To quote from your posting: *Write a shell script.... that will create file of these files with the rm command*. I think it's a quite some challenge to **create** a file by using the `rm` command, so if you find a nice solution for this (except the obvious `rm /dev/null 2>foo`), please let us know   ;-)

Comment: Yes it is very challenging i will posted the solution when i find it... or the right interpretación of the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create test files

```
touch foo foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 "foo difficult" "foo
with
newlines"
```

Write a script `to_delete.sh` that will make a script to delete the foo files

```
for f in foo*; do echo "rm \"$f\""; done > to_delete.sh
```

Edit the file and remove foo3 from being deleted

```
vi to_delete.sh <<END
:/"foo3"/d
:wq
END
```